How to get only hidden/invisible column values in a jQuery Datatable
I am working on a jQuery datatable in which there are 5 rows and 4 columns. I loaded the data in the datatable using a hardcoded dataset. After filtering the first column, there are only 2 rows in the datatable. Rest of the 3 rows are not visible.
How do I get these invisible column values ??? I tried below code. It always gives all the column values in the datatable.
var dt = $('#example').DataTable();
var hiddencols = '';
$.each(dt.columns().visible(), function (key, value) {
    alert(key + ', ' + value);
    if (value == false) {
    
        if (hiddencols == '') {
            hiddencols = key;                        
        } else {
            hiddencols = hiddencols + ',' + key;                        
        }
    }
});

I also tried the below code. It gives only the visible columns.
$('#example').DataTable().rows({ filter: 'applied', page: 'current' }).every(function () {
    var row = this.data();
    alert(row[0]);                
});

How do I get only invisible or hidden column values in jQuery datatable ?

Please clarify: "after filtering first column, there are only 2 rows" - did you mean filter on the first column?   "3 rows are not visible.. how do I get these invisible columns".   Are your columns or rows being hidden?   A complete [mcve] would show how you are filtering (even if it's by code without a filter UI) and give us a starting point to help you.

The rows() doc uses selector-modifier but this doesn't mention a filter:applied parameter.   There is a search parameter with option applied (and removed) - so it seems your code would be $('#example').DataTable().rows({ search: 'removed' edit my bad: "for backwards compatibility, the search term can be provided as filter" - so would be filter:"removed"
